# What is the correct way to use draft mode with arara?

Tags: arara, draft

What is the difference between

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft : yes }
\documentclass{book}
```

and

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[draft]{book}
```

?

Which one is better?

And when I need to run a more complex compilation command list, for example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: frontespizio
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

where should I put the draft option?

Comment: They're very different “draft” modes. The command line option produces no PDF output.

Comment: @egreg Hence if I want the `.pdf` I always have to use the `documentclass` option, have I? What is the `arara` option used for? Only for debugging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `draft: yes` option for `arara` is the same as calling

```
pdflatex -draftmode file
```

which has the effect of doing everything (macro expansion, command execution, writing to auxiliary files) except producing the final PDF file. This saves some time (not much, actually) because it reduces the number of I/O calls.

The `draft` option for `\documentclass` has a very different nature. For the document class itself it doesn't do much, because for the standard classes it just sets `\overfullrule` to 5pt:

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
```

but it is passed to every subsequently loaded package; if a package understands it, it will take the appropriate action. For instance, `graphicx` will disable graphic file inclusion; it will just look at the bounding box and will produce a rectangle with the file name inside. Similarly, `microtype` will be completely disabled.

Note that the `-draftmode` command line has *nothing* to do with the class option. So if you run `pdflatex -draft file` (the command line option can be abbreviated) and the document loads `microtype`, it will not be disabled.

Note also that issuing the `draft` class option for better seeing the overfull boxes should be accompanied by the `final` option to `microtype`, lest you don't want *different* line breaks, which would make `draft` completely ineffective for its purpose.

When to add `draft: yes`? Never, but if you'd like to save a few seconds, on all calls to `pdflatex` except the last one.